# Как подключить yandex speech api к xamarin forms(к кросс-платформенной)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, yandex-speechkit

Я пытаюсь написать голосового помощника, и решил для этого использовать yandex speech api, но тут возникла проблема, инструкция по настройке и установки только для java, c++, python, как подключить к xamarin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Построить общение с YandexSpeechAPI на c# можно с помощью `WebRequest` - `WebResponse`. Посылаете аудио, получаете xml с результатом, парсите. В кратце, так.